# Ricci curvature of the $n$-ball

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Is it true, that Ricci curvature of the $n$-ball is equal to zero? I have calculated it with use of formula
$$
R_{\alpha \beta}=R^{\rho}_{\alpha \rho \beta}=\partial_{\rho} \Gamma^{\rho}_{\beta \alpha}-\partial_{\beta} \Gamma^{\rho}_{\rho \alpha}+\Gamma^{\rho}_{\rho \lambda} \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\beta \alpha}-\Gamma^{\rho}_{\beta \lambda} \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\rho \alpha}
$$

The metric is a standard metric on the ball.

Comment: The full curvature tensor itself is zero...

Comment: Indeed, in the usual (Euclidean) coordinates on the ball, all the Christoffel symbols are identically $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, but I look at the spherical coordinates. And Christoffel symbols are not equal to zero in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Correct, although I'm not sure how you're actually computing with spherical coordinates in an arbitrary $n$ dimensions ($n>3$).

Comment: @TedShifrin it could be calculated in wolfram

Comment: For arbitrary $n$? Pray tell.

Comment: @TedShifrin no, of course ;(